# Collapsable menu CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this layout in CSS3 [image: LEFT: before collapsing. RIGHT: after]

The image on top-left should collapse the vertical menu and show only the images. This should be animated, so it smoothly collapses. I want to do a CSS only solution, no JS/JQuery, no Bootstrap if at all possible. When collapses, the green and yellow boxes should move left as well. Both blue and green boxes should be fixed and the yellow one scrollable.

[This](http://codepen.io/estgad/pen/nDjCI?editors=010) has some potential features I want. [This](http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/showing-and-hiding-content-with-pure-css3.php) is not exactly what I want, and it does not work in my browser.

I am not sure how I can make, with CSS only, the top-left image link to resize the vertical menu, hide only the text of the links (which is not under a span, since I dislike to use it for presentation only), and change its own image. Of course, by clicking again on the new top-right image it should "de-collapse".

One problem I have is that I used padding for the green and yellow boxes as [this Website](http://other.wpengine.com/portfolio/) does, and this seems incorrect to me. They should automatically be readapted to the new layout, without having to toggle the padding.

I have created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9farc4az/).

```
<body>
<header>
<nav>
<a href="#">
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="...html"><img src="option1.jpg">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html"><img src="option2.jpg">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html"><img src="option3.jpg">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<main>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="...html">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html">LINK</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<h1>Main title</h1>
TEXT TEXT TEXT
</main>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Browser support - I would like to address mainly modern browsers, so I will not care much about old IE tricks.

It seems that it is not possible to do it with only CSS (I kind of felt that from my old CSS experience, but was not sure if recent improvements had gone so far to allow it). If JS/JQuery is required, I guess the solution is to capture the click on the image and change the DOM. Not sure how the animation can be done though. And what about the basic layout? Is there a way to keep green&yellow on the left side, close to the blue box, without padding them differently depending on collapse?

Comment: How are you going to attach click events for your menu with css only?

Comment: What sort of browser support are you looking for?

Comment: To do what you want just isn't possible without JS. The *CSS page Layout w/ flexbox* link you referenced works on the principle of *hash link* or *DOM Anchor Hash*. Meaning the menu is hidden by default and shows when the link is clicked on. but then this requires an "close link" as well. For the interaction you want, you "could" try to make a complicated CSS sheet doing this, or you could just use JS, but i doubt the former will ever work like you want without a few hundred lines of CSS

Comment: You might try looking through [**these**](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/) and find something?

Comment: Thanks, I will browse through those examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to achieve a toggle without JS is using the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). Here is a simple example to get you started (clicking menu will toggle the list style):

```css
.main_nav__checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000em;
}


.main_nav__checkbox:checked ~ ul {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" name="togglenav" id="togglenav" class="main_nav__checkbox" aria-label="Toggle Menu" />
  
  <label class="main_nav__toggle" for="togglenav">Menu</label>
  
   <ul>
    <li><a href="...html">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="...html">Option 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  
</nav>
```

Note that there are reasons that this isn't used often:

- It is 'hacky'
- It relies on the `:checked` attribute ( IE9+ )
- It relies on the label checking the checkbox ( a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1037941) made this difficult in the past)

Comment: I saw this option, but the one I saw was not working properly. This one seems to work. However, it is a bit of a hack as you said and I would prefer to avoid it. Your suggestion is helpful though

Answer (score 1):

ya, as mentioned in above answer i've edited your fiddle made it work with that 'hacky' checkbox `:checked` css selector. but i'm unable to animate it though 
try modifying the fiddle or i'll update the answer if i can get the animation to work!!!
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_js/mfyfj211/10/)

Comment: What about the padding of the right containers? How can I make them adaptable to the size of the vertical menu?

Comment: k edited the fiddle but i think i'm gone somewhat wild with selectors there!!